# Hamachi relayed connection

Tags: 16.04

I've been trying to play an old video game with an emulator online. But connecting with Hamachi just won't work, and the reason seems to be a relayed connection. I haven't been able to turn it into direct like it should be. All the istructions i've found from the internet are for windows hamachi and using haguichi as a gui is a bit different. I've tried to find a way to do that using hamachi through terminal, but it still remains relayed.

Help me please and be gentle, i'm just a garbage truck driver :)